# UML of website page navigation

Tags: asp.net, diagram, uml

I need someones help in creating UML for web navigation:

If the dropdown in page1 have values "A" "B" "D"

Web navigates by..

Page1 -> Page2 -> Page 3-> Page 4

if a drop down in page 1 is having value "C" then

Page1 -> Page2 -> Page 4

Please help in creating a UML for this.

Answer (score 1):

Would an activity diagram help? Make each page a rectangle. The decision is a diamond. Your conditions are "c" and "not c".

Answer (score 1):

You can use also activity calls - e.g. in your main activity diagram, you will choose a "box" and that box would be an activity call, which calls activity looking something like this
 pagex->pagey->pagez